# WS2811 RGB LED with arduino

Tags: arduino, power-electronics, rgb

I need to get this model of RGB working with Arduino , I can't find this model on the internet , it's says 12volts.

I need to know how to hook it up ? and if there is an Arduino code that would be great here is a picture of my model.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The WS2811 isn't an LED. Did you happen to come across that bit of info in your searches?

Comment: Did you google "Arduino WS2811"?

Answer (score 0):

For the WS 2811 here some info. With this strips it is possible to realise many effects. Each led segment can be controlled individually. This way it is possible to realise many effects with the remote control and driver that should have come with it. These ledstrips are digital led strips requiring a dedicated controller. Some Arduino libraries seem to be available. There are free libraries for Arduino. AdaFruit NeoPixel and FastLed. You also can look at this link for more information
http://www.instructables.com/id/Bitbanging-step-by-step-Arduino-control-of-WS2811-/

Comment: These seem to be 12v versions. What you picture is for the leds with embedded ws2812. Ops strip has one ws2811 per 3 leds (and 3 channels). The WS2811 has 6-7V VDD. And I am guessing there is a voltage regulator on the back of the module.

Comment: @Passerby: I have removed the picture not to cause confusion.

Comment: @Passerby: Seems i did not remove the picture?

Comment: You removed the picture url but not the markup.